# Vue 3 only sometimes shows the data in the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying my hand at blogging and wanted to build a very simple blog. I have a blog list and a blog details screen. I use the vue-router.
**router/index.js**

```js
...
    {
        path: "/blog",
        name: "Blog",
        component: Blog,
    },
    {
        path: "/blog/:id",
        name: "Details",
        component: BlogPostDetailView,
        props: true
    },   
...
```

In my BlogPostDetail View I only have the following for now:

```js
<template>
    <div v-if="1">
        Post id: {{ id }}
        {{ post }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

    const route = useRoute();
    const id = route.params.id;

    let post = ref({});

    onMounted( async() => {
        const endpoint = "/file/" + id;
        const response = await fetch(endpoint);
        const json = await response.json();
        post = json.data

    });
</script>
```

Now comes the strange behavior! The xhr request is definitely fired and I get a 200 response with data. In the template, however, the data is only displayed once and not on the next refreshes (**F5** or *enter the url*). And if i navidate to other posts als dont display the data but i see in the devtools under the network tab the he is loaded the right data. If I edit something in the template (add a div tag for example) and save it (hot reload). Then shows me the data. but if i refresh it, then dont show me the data.  And I don't understand the behavior at all. What am I missing?

Comment: `the data is only displayed once and not on the next refreshes` What do you mean by refresh? You mean f5? or are you navigating to other blogs with the same URL but different IDs using links?

Comment: You need to use `post.value` instead of assigning a new value to post, see https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html

Comment: @bassxzero I edit my post. i mean F5 or enter the url again.

Comment: @Simon You are right! That is the solution. Thank you very very very much :-) top!